# Using re.search multiple times inside for loop to extract different field values in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I want to retrieve all percentage data as well as integer/float numbers with units from an input text, if it is present in the text. If both are not present together, I want to retrieve atleast the one that is present. Till now if there is an integer/float with an unit in the extracted text, it comes in the result variable.

```
result=[]
    newregex = "[0-9\.\s]+(?:mg|kg|ml|q.s.|ui|M|g|µg)"
    percentregex = "(\d+(\.\d+)?%)"
    for s in zz:
        for e in extracteddata:
            v = re.search(newregex,e,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
            xx = re.search(percentregex,e,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
            if v:

                if e.upper().startswith(s.upper()):
                    result.append([s,v.group(0), e])
            else:
                if e.upper().startswith(s.upper()):
                    result.append([s, e])
```

In the code above, newregex identifies numbers/float with an unit after it, percentregex identifies percentage data, zz and extracteddata are as follows

```
zz = ['HYDROCHLORIC ACID 2M', 'ROPIVACAINE HYDROCHLORIDE MONOHYDRATE', 'SODIUM CHLORIDE', 'SODIUM HYDROXIDE 2M', 'WATER FOR INJECTIONS']

extracteddata = ['Ropivacaine hydrochloride monohydrate for injection (corresponding to 2 mg Ropivacaine hydrochloride anhydrous) 2.12 mg Active ingredient Ph Eur ', 'Sodium chloride for injection 8.6 mg 28% Tonicity contributor Ph Eur ', 'Sodium hydroxide 2M q.s. pH-regulator Ph Eur, NF Hydrochloric acid 2M q.s. pH-regulator Ph Eur, NF ', 'Water for Injections to 1 ml 34% Solvent Ph Eur, USP The product is filled into polypropylene bags sealed with rubber stoppers and aluminium caps with flip-off seals. The primary container is enclosed in a blister. 1(1)']
```

Now I also want to add the condition to extract percentage data in the result variable if it is present but I am stuck with the looping aspect. i want help on using the variable 'xx' to add percentage data to result list if it is present, along with the integer/float numbers with units.

Any help on this.

Updates on attempts made:

```
result = []
    mg = []
    newregex = "[0-9\.\s]+(?:mg|kg|ml|q.s.|ui|M|g|µg)"
    percentregex = "(\d+(\.\d+)?%)"
    print(type(newregex))
    for s in zz:
        for e in extracteddata:
            v = re.search(newregex,e,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
            xx = re.search(percentregex,e,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
            if v:
#                mg.append(v.group(0))

                if e.upper().startswith(s.upper()):
                    result.append([s,v.group(0), e])
            elif v is None:
                if e.upper().startswith(s.upper()):
                    result.append([s, e])
            elif xx:
                if v:
                    if e.upper().startswith(s.upper()):
                        result.append([s,v.group(0),xx.group(0), e])
            elif v is None:
                if  xx:
                    if e.upper().startswith(s.upper()):
                        result.append([s,xx.group(0), e])
            elif v is None and xx is None:
                if e.upper().startswith(s.upper()):
                        result.append([s, e])
            else:
                print("DOne")
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203715/discussion-on-question-by-techsmart-using-re-search-multiple-times-inside-for-lo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Python demo of what we talked about in the comments :

**mod per request**

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> extracteddata = ['"Water 5.5 ml for injections 0.80 and 100 at 2.2 % ','Injections 100 and 0.80', 'Ropivacaine hydrochloride monohydrate for injection (corresponding to 2 mg Ropivacaine hydrochloride anhydrous) 2.12 mg Active ingredient Ph Eur ', 'Sodium chloride for injection 8.6 mg 28% Tonicity contributor Ph Eur ', 'Sodium hydroxide 2M q.s. pH-regulator Ph Eur, NF Hydrochloric acid 2M q.s. pH-regulator Ph Eur, NF ', 'Water for Injections to 1 ml 34% Solvent Ph Eur, USP The product is filled into polypropylene bags sealed with rubber stoppers and aluminium caps with flip-off seals. The primary container is enclosed in a blister. 1(1)']
>>> 
>>> Rx = r"(?i)(?=.*?((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\s*(?:mg|kg|ml|q\.s\.|ui|M|g|µg)))?(?=.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*%))?(?=.*?((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))(?![\d.])(?!\s*(?:%|mg|kg|ml|q\.s\.|ui|M|g|µg)))?.+"
>>> 
>>> for e in extracteddata:
...         match = re.search( Rx, e )
...         print("--------------------------------------------")
...         if match.group(1):
...                 print( "Unit num:  \t\t", match.group(1) )
...         if match.group(2):
...                 print( "Percentage num:  \t", match.group(2) )
...         if match.group(3):
...                 print( "Just a num:  \t\t", match.group(3) )
... 
--------------------------------------------
Unit num:                5.5 ml
Percentage num:          2.2 %
Just a num:              0.80
--------------------------------------------
Just a num:              100
--------------------------------------------
Unit num:                2 mg
--------------------------------------------
Unit num:                8.6 mg
Percentage num:          28%
--------------------------------------------
Unit num:                2M
--------------------------------------------
Unit num:                1 ml
Percentage num:          34%
Just a num:              1
```

This is the regex expanded

```
 (?i)
 (?=
      .*? 
      (                             # (1 start)
           (?:
                \d+ 
                (?: \. \d* )?
             |  \. \d+ 
           )
           \s* 
           (?: mg | kg | ml | q \. s \. | ui | M | g | µg )
      )                             # (1 end)
 )?
 (?=
      .*? 
      (                             # (2 start)
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d+ )?
           \s* %
      )                             # (2 end)
 )?
 (?=
      .*? 
      (                             # (3 start)
           (?:
                \d+ 
                (?: \. \d* )?
             |  \. \d+ 
           )
      )                             # (3 end)
      (?! [\d.] )
      (?!
           \s* 
           (?: % | mg | kg | ml | q \. s \. | ui | M | g | µg )
      )
 )?
 .+
```

As seen it uses three look ahead assertions to find the first instances
of the unit and percentage numbers and stand alone numbers.
All values are unique and not an overlap.

Testing each one for non-empty shows if it found that item(s) in the line.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to update the regex to give preference to float/integers with an unit(mg,ml etc) first and then just floating point values and lastly integers. Because now any number is getting matched in the output. I want to give preference for extraction in the above mentioned order. For example if text contains "Water for injections to 100 to 10 ml", in this case 10 ml will be extracted and not 100 but if text contains "Water for injections 0.80 and 100 ", 0.80 will be extracted and if text contains "Water for injections 100 ", 100 will be extracted.

Comment: Added _just a number_ group. All three groups are unique and are not overlapped.